# Lotus Notes - Start my Reply after Quoted Text

Tags: email, lotus-notes, reply

How to set Lotus notes email replies, so that when I do reply, it starts my reply after the previous quoted text? I searched on google and here without much success. Please help.

Comment: Scroll to the end?

Comment: @DavidPostill I know that you know what I am asking. I would like the email chain to start from top to bottom (oldest to newest).

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes does not provide this feature.

However, before Lotus had implemented a Reply with Internet-Style History feature, I wrote my own version of it as an Action-menu agent, and I top-quoted the history. You would need permission to add agents to your mailbox design in order to use my code. You'd need the Domino Designer client and some knowledge of LotusScript in order to customize the code becuase I wrote it only for myself so it's got my signature hard-coded into it.

Comment: too bad. it seems like a fairly basic feature for a program like this. Unfortunately, I dont think I have a access to Domino designer etc. Thanks.

Comment: 15 years ago I'd have agreed with you, but these days I think top-quoting is considered a flaw, not a feature. Microsoft Outlook doesn't support top-quoting, nor does GMail (as far as I know). I think in the world of business-oriented email, and modern consumer email, it has become accepted that new information belongs at the top so that it's the first thing that the recipient sees when opening the message.

Comment: I agree most (if not all) email clients use this approach. However, it makes it hard and un-intuitive to read the previous email chains. But perhaps, this is the standard. Thanks. Always learn something new at Superuser.